# Hiding price in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want something on woocommerce.

That when I set zero price on a product, it shall not show it (the value) , just set it out of stock.
and hide add to cart button in product page.

Comment: What did you tried already?

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by implementing the **Catalogue Mode**

```
/****** REMOVE THE ADD TO CART BUTTON ****/
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 10 );
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
/*********** REMOVE PRICE FROM ALL PLACES *******/
add_filter( 'woocommerce_variable_sale_price_html', 'theme_remove_prices', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_variable_price_html', 'theme_remove_prices', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'theme_remove_prices', 10, 2 );

function theme_remove_prices( $price, $product ) {
$price = '';
return $price;
}
```

Hope it will help you

Comment: I would like only to products that its price is zero run the command,not for all product.